# ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings is obsolete, it has been replaced by ConfigurationManager.AppSettings

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using this in ASp.net MVC Test project:

`ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["myconn"]` and I get green line under this method saying this method is obsolete and I should use `ConfigurationManager.appsettings` but `configurationManager` is not available in `intellisence` I have included

`using system.Configuration` at the top of Unit Test class.

Comment: You can use [WebConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.webconfigurationmanager.aspx) since this is for a website. You also wouldn't need to add another reference to your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a reference to `System.Configuration` in your project first. Then it will be available in Intellisense.

**Edit:**
There are some basic and legacy methods/classes in the `System.Configuration` namespace included in `System.dll` that is referenced in every project (someone correct me if I'm naming the wrong .dll, but I'm pretty sure that's where they are). When they got rid of the `ConfigurationSettings` class for the `ConfigurationManager` classes, they abstracted the namespace out into its own .dll, but they didn't yank the namespace entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that connection strings should exist in another key in the config:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411.aspx
- http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx